# EE6 web profile ... no EJB container?

Tags: ejb, java-ee-6

I'm learning about Java EE (EE 6 specifically) and find the differences between EJB and EJB Lite a little confusing.

Java EE6 web profile only supports EJB Lite.

My understanding of "EJB Lite" is that it is a simpler subset of EJB (I can find those differences documented easily enough) and you package your EJB classes in a WAR.

So will I only able to access those EJB classes from the webapp contained in the same WAR (or another webapp if I put both of them in the same EAR) ?

I assume that this means that the EJB Lite classes are deployed to the web container.  Does this mean that there is no EJB container in the EE6 web profile ?

(also do we need a web-profile tag?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that EJB lite is shared by both the web profile and the EJB embeddable container.

1.

> So will I only able to access those
>   EJB classes from the webapp contained
>   in the same WAR (or another webapp if
>   I put both of them in the same EAR) ?

Section 20.4.3 of the EJB 3.1 spec:

> The local client view(including the
>   no-interface view) of an enterprise
>   bean component defined within a .war
>   file is only required to be accessible
>   to components within the same .war
>   file. Applications needing access to
>   the local client view of an enterprise
>   bean from a different module in the
>   same application should use an ejb-jar
>   file to define the enterprise bean
>   that exposes the local client view.

Note, the spec allows vendor extensions so that other modules can use the EJBs, but relying on that won't be portable.

2.

> assume that this means that the EJB
>   Lite classes are deployed to the web
>   container. Does this mean that there
>   is no EJB container in the EE6 web
>   profile ?

This is implementation specific, but given the existence of an embeddable EJB container, I suspect most implementations will ship either the full EJB container or a subset.

3.

> (also do we need a web-profile tag?)

No.