# Glassfish 4 Web Profile - Cannot access remote EJB

Tags: jndi, glassfish-4

I cannot access remote EJB beans of our application server within a web application running on Glassfish 3 web-profile using jndi lookup.

Using full profile for our web-application or even testing with a console application we have no problem accessing jndi remote beans.

**Exception:**

```
Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext
```

We just hoped to make our web servers more lightweight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Web Profile` version of Glassfish only contains `EJB Lite`, which doesn't support `@Remote` interfaces. You need the `Full Profile` which supports the full EJB 3 spec.

From the [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beanr/index.html):

> The Web Profile of the GlassFishTM Server supports the EJB 3.1 Lite
>   specification, which allows enterprise beans within web applications,
>   among other features. The full GlassFish Server supports the entire
>   EJB 3.1 specification. For details, see JSR 318.

You can find a comparision of features included in `Web Profile` and `Full Profile` [here](https://glassfish.java.net/webprofileORfullplatform31x.html) (It was made for Glassfish 3.1.1 but it should be nearly the same for Glassfish 4 except some newer versions of some features). You can find a nice feature comparision between EJB 3.1 Lite and Full in [this article](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1321142/Part-Three-New-Features-in-EJB-31).

**Update:**

As you wrote in the comment (and the initial question) you are not using any enterprise beans directly in your web application, but you are retrieving bean instances via JNDI. This doesn't work with the `Web Profile` of Glassfish because the functionality for remote lookups is not there, e.g. the `CORBA` and `ORB` modules are missing (there are some basic `CORBA OMG` APIs but only because they are needed by other modules).

**As your goal was to make the server more lightweight, maybe this is another option for you:** 
 You can remove unused components and modules with the `pkg` command-line-tool or with the graphical utility `updatetool`. You could install the `Full Profile` of Glassfish and then remove obsolete components step by step to make the server more lightweight. More details about the tools can be found in the [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2435/gkscq.html).

**See also:**

- [Can EJB 3.1 Lite be exposed via Remote interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711970/can-ejb-3-1-lite-be-exposed-via-remote-interface)
- [How to know what glassfish is - full plaform or web profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459967/how-to-know-what-glassfish-is-full-plaform-or-web-profile)
- [EE6 web profile … no EJB container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286934/ee6-web-profile-no-ejb-container)
- [GLASSFISH-14459 corba classes are part of web profile](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-14459)

Comment: Maybe my question was not documented enough. There are no enterprise beans within my web application. I am using jndi to look them up remotely from different server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There are also some config settings like jms factory, or datasources which are not needed in war profile. So i have to remove components and test which settings are not needed.